# How to scrape wikipedia if you already have all the urls?

Tags: python, r, web-scraping

I have the a table of information below that contains 1000 of these entries and the sum of the first column is approximately 90 000.

| counts | genus species |
| --- | --- |
| 14149 | Marchantia polymorpha |
| 9345 | Physcomitrium patens |
| 7744 | Selaginella moellendorffii |
| 5389 | Picea sitchensis |

For each of the 1000 entries I would like to search the Wikipedia page and extract the grouping of the organism.

For example:

I look up Marchantia polymorpha in Wikipedia and find it's page. On the right most side of the page is the scientific classification of the species. I would like to extract the value for Kingdom i.e. Plantae (amongst others) in this case.

[image: Wikipedia results page]

At the end of searching and extracting I would like a table that looks like this:

| counts | genus species | kingdom |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14149 | Marchantia polymorpha | plantae |
| 9345 | Physcomitrium patens | plantae |
| 7744 | Selaginella moellendorffii | plantae |
| 5389 | Picea sitchensis | fungi |

So that I can count the total number of entries belonging to each kingdom.

Collecting the URLs won't be difficult. Since the base URL is the same and the page I want to end up on simply adds the genus_species name. For example all the URLs for the list above would be:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marchantia_polymorpha  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physcomitrium_patens  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selaginella_moellendorffii  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picea_sitchensis
```

I am not 100% certain that a Wikipedia page exists for each genus but the majority do based on manual searches I've done previously.

Comment: Just a thought. Are you sure Wikipedia is the best source for this?  The Encyclopedia of Life provides a searchable API which should suit your needs and both more authoritative and more complete. https://eol.org/docs/what-is-eol/data-services

Comment: thanks for this. it is not the best source no, I was just choosing because of my familiarity with the site. I will eventually have to generate a figure from a more reputable source so eol will be perfect. Perhaps once I've learnt the ropes of scaping I can move onto this because I am totally unfamiliar with this website.

Comment: Every time you want to scrape Wikipedia, remember it has [an API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) - a much friendlier set of URL for machine-readable representation

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, but I am not sure if it will work on all Wikipedia sites:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marchantia_polymorpha'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
# It is in an table row:
tr = soup.find_all('tr')
for t in tr:
    if 'kingdom' in t.text.lower():
        text = t.text
        break
text.replace('\n', '').split(':')[1]
>>> 'Plantae'

# Or since both kingdom and plantea are in a <td>
td = soup.find_all('td')
for i, t in enumerate(td):
    if 'kingdom' in t.text.lower():
        kingdom = td[i+1].text.rstrip() # in the row after kingdom is plantae (i+1)

print(kingdom)
>>> 'Plantae'
```

Comment: Thanks this works, I am looking into some edge cases. Some of the information is in domains as opposed to kingdoms. Could I somewhat easily (as an amateur) extend that to an if, else if situation? Secondly, how do I expand this to do the search for my list of urls all in one go?

Comment: You can create a function and use `apply` for pandas. About the edge cases I would suggest you to look in to source of a website and just try it. For example using an `if` you can also extract `Division` and other information from the website.